UFW to restrict access on second NIC
I am running a cloud based Ubuntu 22.04 server with a public and with another non routable IP address (DigitalOcean)
I am trying to limit access to the second IP address for a Tinc VPN which uses port 655/UDP.
Currently I use the command:
sudo ufw allow in on eth1 from 10.130.1.1 port 655 proto udp

the ufw status output is
Anywhere on eth1           ALLOW       10.130.1.1 655/udp

I believe that a result
655/UDP on eth1            ALLOW       10.130.1.1  655/UDP

will be a stricter limitation.
Is there a way to achieve my preferred option using UFW and should I bother?
My goal is that I would like to limit the traffic on eth1 to only 655/UDP coming to eth1 and actually on eth1
